# Compiling and running multiple packages using the command line in Java

Tags: java, command-line

I have been using an IDE but now, in order to prepare my 1Z0-803 exam, I need to run and compile from the command line.  The problem is that I have multiple packages and I have tried to find the answer but nothing has worked so far.

So I have :

```
package com.oca.tutorial;

import com.oca.tutorial.planets.Earth;
import com.oca.tutorial.planets.Mars;
import com.oca.tutorial.planets.Venus;

public class GreetingUniverse {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("greetings universe");

        new Earth();
        new Mars();
        new Venus();
        }
}
```

Venus class:

```
package com.oca.tutorial.planets;

public class Venus {

    public Venus() {

        System.out.println("Hello from Venus");

    }

}
```

Mars class

```
 package com.oca.tutorial.planets;

    public class Mars {


        public Mars (){

            System.out.println("Hello from Mars");


        }

    }
```

And my Earth class

```
 package com.oca.tutorial.planets;

    public class Earth {


        public Earth (){

            System.out.println("Hello from earth");


        }

    }
```

Command Line + error 
[image]

Expected output:

```
greetings universe
Hello from earth
Hello from Mars
Hello from Venus
```

Fiel Structure for planets :

```
C:\OCA\com\oca\tutorial\planets
```

Fiel Structure for main GreetingUniverse :

```
C:\OCA\GreetingUniverse
```

error message from command prompt:

[image]

Comment: Your question ends with "Command Line + error", but you do not say what you tried and what the error is.  Can you add this?

Comment: What is the file structure under your `OCA` directory?

Comment: @brettjonesdev Theres a screenshot below that that you probably aren't seeing for some reason

Comment: p.s. You can copy and paste from the Windows command prompt by clicking on the icon in the upper left corner. This is preferrable to a screenshot when asking for help here because you can provide *all* the errors.

Comment: @Steve Ah, gotcha.  Stupid filtered internet...

Comment: Not working. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that all files can be found by the compiler. Go to the directory containing the `com` folder and use:

```
javac -d classes com\oca\tutorial\GreetingUniverse.java
```

or simply

```
javac -d classes com\oca\tutorial\*.java
```

with this file structure

```
com
 |-oca
    |-tutorial
       |  GreetingUniverse.java
       |-planets
          Earth.java
          Mars.Java
          Venus.java
```

You need to be located in `C:\OCA` when doing the compilation.

Comment: i will try this. Hold on please

Comment: You will need to create a classes folder if it doesnt already exist for the output class files

Comment: This is exactly the structure i have in my folder OCA folder

Comment: You need to be located in `C:\OCA` when doing the compilation

Answer (score 1):

First you can cd to the base directory, where com/ is located. Then,

`javac -d bin com\oca\tutorial\*.java com\oca\tutorial\planets\*.java`

**Edit:**
As the above posters say (and discovered), your file structure is wrong. If you have class GreetingUniverse in package `com.oca.tutorial`, then file path should be com\oca\tutorial\GreetingUniverse.java.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you declare packages for each of your classes. `GreetingUniverse` is in the `com.oca.tutorial` package and `Venus`, `Mars`, and `Earth` are in the `com.oca.tutorial.planets` package. Java requires that a .java file is located in a directory which mirrors its package name. For example, `GreetingUniverse.java` needs to be in a subdirectory called `com\oca\tutorial`. This subdirectory can be in the `OCA` directory which you are currently using to compile from.

If you still get similar errors after moving your .java files to the correct directories, try including all the .java files for every class in the same command-line. It has been a long time since I compiled large-ish projects from the command-line. From what I remember this shouldn't be necessary, but it is certainly worth a try.

**Edit:**

To clarify, this is how your directory structure should be set up:

> C:
>   +-- OCA
>     +-- com
>       +-- oca
>         +-- tutorial
>           -- GreetingUniverse.java
>         +-- planets
>           -- Earth.java
>           -- Mars.java
>           -- Venus.java

Now run the following command:

> C:\OCA> javac com/oca/tutorial/GreetingUniverse.java

Comment: @Rahoul Please remember to upvote any helpful answers and click the checkmark to accept the one that helps you the most. Good luck with your Java!

Comment: I just tried to move GreetingUniverse.java into com\oca\tutorial under the same path of com.oca.tutorial.planets but ... please see new screenshot

Comment: @Rahoul You need to compile from `C:\OCA` and provide the relative path to the .java file you want to compile (e.g. `javac com/oca/tutorial/GreetingUniverse.java`. Don't cd to the subdirectory because `javac` will then be unable to find the other .java files.

Comment: @Rahoul What does "Not working mean"? I'm glad to continue to help you if you provide more information about your most recent attempt.