# Bash Script to execute Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, bash, maven, command-line

I usually compile and execute from Java project using eclipse IDE. Now, I need to write a bash script to submit this task to a cluster. My project contains 3 packages and has been written as per the Maven architecture. Can anyone hint me as to how can I include the task of executing the java program in the my bash script?

I tried different things like first trying to execute the project using command line but it does not work. I already read the replies provided in this post: [Compiling and running multiple packages using the command line in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841819/compiling-and-running-multiple-packages-using-the-command-line-in-java) and some others, but didn't help.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: go through Maven App Assembler plugin

Comment: @SSP any reason you mention this a comment rather than up-vote my answer which says basically the same thing?

Comment: I did not saw that. will delete it and upvote for you.

Comment: It's happened becaz when i open this question there was no answer.

Comment: @SSP: good deal, and odd; usually I see comments and answers stream in almost instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you look into something like the [Maven App Assembler plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/). I don't know about your cluster but the mentioned plugin can create run scripts for most major OSes and is highly configurable.